# getting error in using sentinel::login on laravel 7

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-7, sentinel

i have an issue in creating Login with Sentinel.
this code, works perfectly as the user has registered in the system. But, when it cant find the user, i get this error:

**Argument 1 passed to Cartalyst\Sentinel\Sentinel::login() must implement interface Cartalyst\Sentinel\Users\UserInterface, bool given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\portal\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade.php on line 261**

here is the code:

```
$user = Sentinel::authenticate($request->all());
if (Sentinel::check($user)){
        Sentinel::login($user);
        return redirect('/');
}
else{
    return redirect()->back();
}
```

how should I fix this? thanks

Comment: what's result of `$request->all()`

Comment: it returns back an array of email and password